# how to set the size of a modal window

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've just started learning ios programming.

I want to show a modal window in a specific size when my application launches.
So, in my view controller, I wrote this code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    ModalViewController *modal;
    modal = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    modal.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

    [self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

With this code, the modal window shows up, but, it shows up with the size that fits screen size.

I want my modal window shows up with the size I set to.

How can I make it work?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];   
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, <width>, <height>);
}
```

or

```
ViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
ViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
ViewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
ViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                                    // Calcuation based on landscape orientation (width=height) 
                                                                    ([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height/2)-(320/2),// X
                                                                    ([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width/2)-(320/2),// Y
                                                                    320,// Width
                                                                    320// Height
                                                                    );
```

or Try replacing the last line with this

```
ViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! I copy the code above and paste it in my view controlloer, but it didn't make difference. Should I keep my code I posted and add your code in the same view controller?

Comment: By the way, this view controller is added to navigation controller in AppDelegate.m. I don't know if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

ModalViewController *modal=[[LoginViewController alloc] init];
modal.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height);
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your support! I tried your code, but it didn't work. does it matter that this view controller is added to navigation controller in appDelegate.m?