# How to set Modal screen size and make the background opaque?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, size, transparency

I already have an answer and wanted to share it here since I didn't find it anywhere before. Even reading issues at GitHub. I solved using android and hooks but it would be great to see if there are other solutions and compile all of them.

An older question (2013) using iphone:

- [how to set the size of a modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107447/how-to-set-the-size-of-a-modal-window)

Answer (score 0):

I left here an example that works well. You must wrap the code inside the Modal component with a View and then set the margin. If you wanna set an opacity background you must use another View component and set its background color using RGBA's transparency in order to avoid using opacity that will make opaque all inside it (even your Modal's pop-up). The "flex:1" at the first View inside the Modal is a way to sets the screen size. In this case, I covered the whole screen.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(true)}
            >
              <View  style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)', flex:1}}>
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', padding: 40, margin: 80}}>
                        <Text>This is a modal</Text>
                        <Button title='close'
                            onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)} />
                    </View>

                </View>
            </Modal>

            <Button
                title="Press me"
                onPress={() =>setModalVisible(true)}
            />

        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(25, 90, 90)',
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```